# WordPress sanitize tel

Tags: wordpress

I have referred to https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/, and there are many great functions for sanitization/escaping. But I don't see one that is specifically for `tel`? Do I use `sanitize_text_field()` for `tel` or there is any other better/suitable one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use php FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT

https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php